# Akonadi personal infromation management service is not running

Tags: 16.04, mysql, akonadi

I am getting this error (`Akonadi personal information management service is not running. This application cannot be used without it`) when I attempt to open Knotes on my system (Ubuntu 16.04). I tried to start the service but it always fails.

Upon installing Akonadi console and troubleshooting, I get the error shown in the screenshot below.

[image]